# Is there a way to go back one directory in python?

Tags: python, json

Im trying to access `users_info.json` from `economy.py`
To do that i need to go back one directory, i've tried `../bot_data/users_info.json` but i get this error :

`Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../bot_data/users_info.json'`

```
    with open("../bot_data/users_info.json") as f:
       users_info = json.load(f)
```

Directory:

bot_data

- users_info.json

cogs

- economy.py

Both `cogs` and `bot_data` are in the same directory

Comment: Please include the code in the question as text instead of in a linked image. As for the issue, I suspect that your working directory will already be one level up (where the script you're running is) and so you don't need to go up one level. Have you tried just `bot_data/users_info.json`?

Comment: I've edited and yes, i tried 'bot_data/users_info.json'

Comment: What is the current directory?   It must be `cogs` for your relative path to work. Try `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: `import os`  before running `os.getcwd()`

Comment: Nvm, i manage to find the mistake


I had to write "./bot_data/users_info.json" insead of "../bot_data/users_info.json"